# keyboard shortcuts misbehavior Gnome 3.6

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I've enabled few Keyboard-shortcuts and they **work weird**.

1. **Shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**

   I've enabled <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open a Google-chrome browser. 
   Works only when I hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> for a while. 
   Works fine for default shortcuts like lock-screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>) and gnome-terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. **Shortcuts with <kbd>Super</kbd>+**
   I've enabled "Super+F" to open a Google-chrome browser with facebook URL
   Works only if I press "F" twice without releasing the "Super" key

---

Can someone help me fixing the issue (or) Confirm this behavior/bug?

OS - Ubuntu 12.10
Gnome - 3.6 (PPA)

Comment: I have similar strange behavior on 14.04, all modifier doesn't work well (control,shift,.. ) I have to press many time to get control+c  works ... very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the "Show location of pointer" using the Gnome Tweak Tool.